# Excepción PHP Java Brigde

Tags: php, java, tomcat

Estoy ejecutando código PHP en un servidor Tomcat con el PHP Java Brigde. El servidor funciona correctamente y recibe y procesa las peticiones.
Pero algunas veces, el servidor muestra un error 500 y no procesa la petición.
El error aparece de manera aleatoria e intermitente, en un 5% de las peticiones aproximadamente.

Como ocurre pocas veces, no sé muy bien que puede estar ocurriendo.
En el log, se guarda el siguiente error:

```
May 03, 2022 7:42:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [PhpCGIServlet] in context with path [/tetrashop] threw exception
php.java.fastcgi.ConnectionException
    at php.java.fastcgi.FCGIInputStream.read(FCGIInputStream.java:31)
    at php.java.fastcgi.FCGIHeaderParser.parseBody(FCGIHeaderParser.java:82)
    at php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doExecute(FastCGIServlet.java:424)
    at php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.execute(FastCGIServlet.java:516)
    at php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:527)
    at php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doPost(FastCGIServlet.java:539)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Protocol error
    at php.java.fastcgi.FCGIInputStream.doRead(FCGIInputStream.java:56)
    at php.java.fastcgi.FCGIInputStream.read(FCGIInputStream.java:29)
    ... 30 more
```

¿Alguien sabe qué problema hay y como se podría solucionar?

Gracias

Comment: si colocas el log completo ayudaría más

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.